# Blender 3.5 hair system UV map

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, hair

I am trying to create carpets for my asset browser with the new blender 3.5 hair system.
When trying to shade the hair, the UV map doesn't match the surface - eventhough it should have the uv input of the "Interpolate Hair Curves" node.

[image]

I also tried adding an "Attach Hair Curves to Surface" node with the UV input of the surface, still no success.

Does anyone have an idea what i'm doing wrong, or is it just a bug that needs to be fixed?

[image: uv maps not matching]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which UV map do you use in the hair shader (material)? *surface_uv_coordinate* instead of *UVMap* should do the trick. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/280096/107598

Answer (score 0):

the hair's have an attribute called *surface_uv_coordinates*. use an *attribute* node in the shader editor with that name (*surface_uv_coordinates*), and you should have the correct uv map.