# How do I apply a pre-existing UvMap to a color attribute?

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I'm working on a viva piñata styled fur in geometry nodes, but ran into an issue, I'm trying to make the fur use the same Uvs as the base mesh, but I don't know how to add the map to the color when it's a attribute, I've been pretty much banging my head against the wall trying to find a way to combine them, but my peanut brain has been stumped the whole time. Does anyone know what changes to the shader/geometry node tree I can make?
Edit: not entirely sure if this is important, but I'm using instances, and need each individual instance to have multiple colors, therefore why I want to use this method, because right now, even without the correct Uvs, they have multiple colors, and no other methods I've tried so far have done this.[image: node+shadertree]

Comment: this is a duplicate.
see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/291021/165102
and: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/280101/165102