# Fur texture distorted

Tags: texturing, uv, particles, hair

I set up a hair particle system in Blender and tried to project the color from my model onto the fur. However, when rendering, my fur has the color but it's distorted, and even with texture coordinates, I am unable to fix it. I think this might have something to do with hair interpolation, but I can't figure it out. I am also new to hair particles, so I hope someone with more experience can help me here. I use Blender 3.6. [My file](https://mega.nz/file/5jNSVRhQ#ATd8-32VG6GE0pJCtMKV40hLQQ18Z3XRQIPq2k_9EBA)

[image]

Comment: you need to use the "surface_uv_coordinate" attribute as UV map to map color to the hair. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/280101/107598