# New Hair Curves: Can't transfer color from faces

Tags: color, hair

[image]

I have applied different color materials to cube faces and then added a new hair curves. Is there any easy way to transfer mesh faces color to hair material? Sorry for noob question

Comment: The *surface_uv_coordinate* attribute is a vector. It's like a UV map. You need to use it for the *Vector* input of a *Image Texture* node.  Have a look at the answer of this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/280096/107598

Comment: Thank you, but I don't quite understand what image texture to use there (in Image Texture node) as I just need just faces color

Comment: Ok, so the cube has no image texture. And you want to have the hair the same color the cube has, right? How does the cube material look like in the shader editor?

Comment: Has each side of the cube its own material?

Comment: Yes, one face of a cube is assigned another material, just a principled BSDF with color [link](https://imgur.com/85Z1LsP)

Comment: I don't think that you can assign the colors of 2 materials to one *Curves* object. It should work with just one material. Or 2 *Curves* objects. For just one material, you could use a mask to define which side of the cube. Or use a painted image texture. Or vertex colors. These info can be accessed by the material of *Curves* object.